# How to find a number in an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a method to find a number in an array.I have thought to possible solutions but I don't know how to do.I have searched in internet but I have found nothing...

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].indexOf(2)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: or this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: *"I have searched in internet but I have found nothing"* - Um...If you type your question's title into Google you'll immediately get results for how to do this in several programming languages, which obviously you can then narrow down just by adding "javascript" to your query.

Comment: What does "find" mean? Do you want to check if it's there? The index?

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla documentation:

> Using indexOf()
>
> The following example uses indexOf() to locate values in an array.

```
var array = [2, 9, 9];
array.indexOf(2);     // 0
array.indexOf(7);     // -1
array.indexOf(9, 2);  // 2
array.indexOf(2, -1); // -1
array.indexOf(2, -3); // 0
```

> Finding all the occurrences of an element

```
var indices = [];
var array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'];
var element = 'a';
var idx = array.indexOf(element);
while (idx != -1) {
  indices.push(idx);
  idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
}
console.log(indices);
// [0, 2, 4]
```